# Magento 2 - Correct way of Module Installation

Tags: php, magento2, module

Trying to install sample module in Magento 2 from [this](https://github.com/darshanb87/magento2-extension-example). Below is the module structure `app/code/NameSpace/Module/`

[image: module image]

**module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magentostudy_News" setup_version="0.0.1" schema_version="0.0.1"/>
</config>
```

**composer.json**

```
{
    "name": "magentostudy/module-news",
    "description": "N/A",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.5.0|~5.6.0|~7.0.0",
        "magento/module-store": "100.0.0",
        "magento/module-email": "100.0.0",
        "magento/module-ui": "100.0.0",
        "magento/framework": "100.0.0"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [ "registration.php" ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Magentostudy\\News\\": ""
        }
    }
    }
```

**Registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magentostudy_News',
    __DIR__
);
```

Executing below command to enable module

```
php ./bin/magento module:enable Magentostudy_News
```

It says `there are no commands defined in the "module" namespace.` Also on frontend it throws below exception. I am using composer but not github.

`Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Source class "\Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\Setup" for "Magento\Framework\Module\Updater\SetupFactory" generation does not exist.'`

**CODE EDIT**

Added `Setup` folder with file `InstallSchema.php` which includes below code

```
    <?php
/**
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014 X.commerce, Inc. (http://www.magentocommerce.com)
 */

/* @var $installer \Magento\Setup\Module\SetupModule */

namespace Magentostudy\News\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;

$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

/**
 * Creating table magentostudy_news
 */
$table = $installer->getConnection()->newTable(
    $installer->getTable('magentostudy_news')
)->addColumn(
    'news_id',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_INTEGER,
    null,
    ['identity' => true, 'unsigned' => true, 'nullable' => false, 'primary' => true],
    'Entity Id'
)->addColumn(
    'title',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    255,
    ['nullable' => true],
    'News Title'
)->addColumn(
    'author',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    255,
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'Author'
)->addColumn(
    'content',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    '2M',
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'Content'
)->addColumn(
    'image',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
    null,
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'News image media path'
)->addColumn(
    'created_at',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TIMESTAMP,
    null,
    ['nullable' => false],
    'Created At'
)->addColumn(
    'published_at',
    \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_DATE,
    null,
    ['nullable' => true,'default' => null],
    'World publish date'
)->addIndex(
    $installer->getIdxName(
        'magentostudy_news',
        ['published_at'],
        \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX
    ),
    ['published_at'],
    ['type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\AdapterInterface::INDEX_TYPE_INDEX]
)->setComment(
    'News item'
);
$installer->getConnection()->createTable($table);
$installer->endSetup();
```

1. What is the correct way to install **Magento 2** modules ?
2. Any crucial step I missed ?

Reference URL : http://mageinferno.com/blog/setting-up-magento-2-module-right-way-composer-packagist

Comment: your reference also have good and resourceful information to learn. However, following is the more detailed reference about Magento 2 modules: https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-1-setup/

Comment: there are lots of changes in your sample module because this module made  on magento beta version not stable version, And latest stable version of magento2.0 lots of changes added like , noNamespaceSchemaLocation path has been changed,,,I would suggest please follow other blog for magento2 sample module

Comment: @KeyurShah, if you could guide on stable mage-2 modules.

Comment: @Vikram you can use https://www.ashsmith.io/magento2/module-from-scratch-module-part-1-setup/ for magento2 module reference

Answer (score 2):

You can install Magento 2 extension easily from any VCS (github or bitbcuket) if the module is packed with proper composer.json file.

For example, in order to install [Easy Template Path Hints 2](https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints) extension, you just have to run two commands for installation:

```
composer config repositories.magesycho-magento2-easy-template-path-hints git git@github.com:MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints.git
composer require magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints:dev-master
```

**Explanation:**

**1>** Registering the module git repository

```
composer config repositories.magesycho-magento2-easy-template-path-hints git git@github.com:MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints.git
```

Composer config repository command syntax looks like:

```
composer config repositories.<unique-repo-name> <vcs-type> <vcs-url-https-or-sshl>
```

Composer will register a new repository to composer.json (under "repositories" node). Updated composer.json looks like:

```
{  
  "repositories": {
    "magesycho-magento2-easy-template-path-hints": {
      "type": "git",
      "url": "git@github.com:MagePsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints.git"
    }
  }
}
```

**2>** Registering the module package itself

```
composer require magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints:dev-master
```

Composer require command syntax:

```
composer require <vendor>/<package>:dev-<branch>
```

This will add new dependent package under node “require” as:

```
{
  "name": "magento/magento2ce",
  "description": "Magento 2 (Community Edition)",
  "type": "project",
  "require": {
    "magepsycho/magento2-easy-template-path-hints": "dev-master"
  }
}
```

and download the module from the repo.

And if you have extension zip file, just extract it and copy it to the `app/code/` folder - as that simple.

Once the Module is installed, you can simply enable it using following commands:

```
php bin/magento module:enable MagePsycho_Easypathhints --clear-static-content
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more about the role of composer config and require here? How does it work?

Comment: @amitshree updated!

Comment: @MagePsycho, what if I need to develop a simple `hello world` module without github or bitbcuket OR a client specific module which will not be on and VCS ? The point here is to have a clear and  correct approach to install Magento 2 modules and also to avoid any pitfalls. It would be great if you could shed some light.

Comment: @Vikram Please check if that sounds helpful.

Comment: @MagePsycho so custom code written for almost every custom site-build out there belongs in app/code/ ? Moreover, do all modules regardless of location, should have a composer.json and a registration.php ?